# How to retry when I get "An error has occurred - please retry your request"

Tags: bug, voting

When my network is down and I try to vote something, I get this error: `An error has occurred - please retry your request`. But the vote button is still red and after connecting to the network, I can't retry my request. The only way to retry is to refresh the page and press the vote button again. Is there a better way to retry voting request?

**Screenshot:**

> [image]

Comment: Well, the wording is confusing, I agree. You can simply click the vote arrow again, even though it's already "red".

Comment: Can you be more specific on the red button? *What* red button? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I have tried clicking the red arrow again, but it is not working. After refreshing the page, the arrow is "not red".

Comment: Did you have the site open on two or more tabs and logout of one of them?

Comment: No. I never logout of SO !

Comment: So, the bug here is that the upvote button is highlighted even though the upvote failed. It should stay gray in such case.